# "element-ui" table How to change empty cells as '-'.

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

```js
var Main = {
      data() {
        return {
          tableData: [{
            date: '2016-05-03',
            name: 'Tom',
            address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
          }, {
            date: '2016-05-02',
            name: '',
            address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
          }, {
            date: '2016-05-04',
            name: '',
            address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
          }, {
            date: '2016-05-01',
            name: 'Tom',
            address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles'
          }]
        }
      }
    }
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.4.11/lib/theme-chalk/index.css");
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.4.11/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<template>
    <el-table :data="tableData" style="width: 100%">
      <el-table-column prop="date" label="Date" width="180">
      </el-table-column>
      <el-table-column prop="name" label="Name" width="180">
        <template slot-scope="scope">
          {{scope.row.name || '-'}}
        </template>
      </el-table-column>
      <el-table-column prop="address" label="Address">
      </el-table-column>
    </el-table>
  </template>
</div>
```

I know If I use 'template' tag I can convert null data as '-'.
now let's suppose that I have more than 100 tables and I don't know which cells can be null.
 putting 'template' to all el-table-columns will be very hard work and inefficient way.
I want to know is there any way that I can change empty cells as '-' at the same time. help me guys
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uwjgbosd/6/)

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just :

```
<template>
<el-table :data="tableData" style="width: 100%">
  <el-table-column prop="date" label="Date" width="180">
  </el-table-column>
  <el-table-column prop="name" label="Name" width="180">
    <template slot-scope="scope">
      <!-- Replace empty cell by '-' --->
      <div class="cell" v-if="scope.row.name !== null">{{ scope.row.answer }}</div>
      <div v-else class="cell">-</div>
    </template>
  </el-table-column>
  <el-table-column prop="address" label="Address">
  </el-table-column>
</el-table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Latest code: change slot-scope to #default:

```
<template>
  <el-table :data="tableData" style="width: 100%">
    <el-table-column empty="NA" prop="date" label="Date" width="180" />
    <el-table-column prop="name" label="Name" width="180" >
    <template #default="scope">
        <div style="display: flex; align-items: center">
            <div class="cell" v-if="scope.row.name !== ''">{{ scope.row.name }}</div>
            <div v-else class="cell">-</div>
        </div>
      </template>
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column prop="address" label="Address" />
  </el-table>
</template>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure there are many ways to achieve that. But try this:

```js
computed: {
  items() {
    let data = this.tableData;

    for(let item of data) {
      for(let key in item) {
        if (!item[key]) {
          item[key] = '-';
        }
      }
    }

    return data;
  }
}
```

```vue
<template>
  <el-table :data="items" style="width: 100%">
  <! -- the rest of the content -->
```

Comment: If I do this way, I should reprocess all data by using for loop.
I wonder that is there any way that I can change all of empty-cells into '-' at the same time, not changing real data

Comment: Well, you shouldn't be worrying too much about reprocessing of data since [computed properties are cached based on their dependencies](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods). A computed property will only re-evaluate when some of its dependencies have changed.

Comment: Otherwise, you could create a proxy method that parses the individual items as they're being rendered. BTW, why can't you do the processing on server-side?

Comment: As I supposed in question, if I have more than 100 tables and same amount of data I should make same numbers of computed function.
and I'm trying to don't reprocess data on server-side because of reusability.